# Real values of a function involving the Lambert $W(x)$ function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, lambert-w

I have the following function:
$$y=-\dfrac{W\left(-\ln(k)\right)}{\ln(k)}$$ 
where $W(x)$ is the Lambert $W$ function defined as the solution of the equation:
$$x=W(x)e^{W(x)}$$
If $k\in\mathbb{R}$ and $k\gt 0$, for what values of $k$, $y$ is real?
I found heuristically that the value of $k$ should be in the range $1.44\lt k\lt 1.45$. How can I found it analitically, or how can I get the best approximation for the maximum value of $k$ for which the solution is real? Thanks.

Comment: The Lambert $W$ is defined by $z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$, not $W^W$.

Comment: @Dr.MV: Just a typo. I corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse function of $y$ is given by $\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)^{-\frac{1}{y}}$, hence it is enough to locate the maximum of $g(x)=x^{-x}$ over $\mathbb{R}^+$ to get that the domain of $y$ is given by 
$$ \left(0,\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{-\frac{1}{e}}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

> Notice, for the 'Product Log Function' (or the Lambert $\text{W}$-function) is defined as follows:
>
> $$f(z)=ze^z\to z=f^{-1}(ze^z)=\text{W}(ze^z)$$

---

Now, we know that for $k\in\mathbb{R}^+$ (real, and bigger than zero) $\ln(k)$ is well defined.

Now, your question is about:

$$y(k)=k^{k^{k^{k^{\dots}}}}=-\frac{\text{W}\left(-\ln(k)\right)}{\ln(k)}$$

Eisenstein's (1844) considered this series of the infinite [power tower](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerTower.html). $y(k)$ converges iff $e^{-e}\le k\le e^{\frac{1}{e}}$; OEIS [A073230](http://oeis.org/A073230) and [A073229](http://oeis.org/A073229)), as shown by Euler (1783) and Eisenstein (1844) (Le Lionnais 1983; Wells 1986, p. 35).

So, the domain of $y(k)$:

$$\left[0,e^{\frac{1}{e}}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

The Lambert W function has two real branches.  For $W_0$, your domain is $(0,\exp(1/e))$ as noted by Jack.  For $W_{-1}$, your domain is $(1,\exp(1/e))$.

[image: WW]
$y=-\dfrac{W_0\left(-\ln(k)\right)}{\ln(k)}$ (red) and $y=-\dfrac{W_{-1}\left(-\ln(k)\right)}{\ln(k)}$ (blue)